# Airport Extreme not working with new modem

Tags: wifi, airport, internet

I have an Airport Extreme that was previously connected to a, well lets say not great modem. So I replaced the modem with 'Nucleus Connect', which is Fibre I think. (I live in Singapore and they installed this here). And I have a problem, my airport extreme just does not work anymore! I plug it into the modem and power source, but it flashes amber. Here is what I have done:

- Factory default reset
- Power down computers
- Power down airport extreme
- Power down modem

So what now!? In my Airport Utility here are the problems:

- No DNS Servers
- No Internet Connection

Also, the router shows up sporadically in Airport Utility and when it does,  it shows up but with a warning sign and my only option is to forget it.

Can someone point me to troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you plugged your computer directly into the modem with ethernet to make sure the modem is connected to the internet? Are you sure the ethernet cable you're using to connect the AirPort to the modem is good and plugged into the WAN port on the Airport?

Comment: My modem is indeed connected to the internet, today I got the installation guys offered me a new router after I asked this question and it works. But I love my airport extreme! And I want it working with this modem! I will try the WAN port thing and get back to you

Comment: So you can connect your computer directly to the modem and get online, yes? The "WAN port thing" is the only way to plug a router into a modem like yours: Airport Extreme routers have 1 WAN port and 3 LAN ports for taking ethernet out. Sometimes in haste people plug the modem into one of the LAN ports. Just checking the hardware...

Comment: @Richard I am pretty sure it is in the WAN port, the one which has a gray circle indicator

Comment: That sounds right. And are you sure your computer can get online when connected directly to the modem with Ethernet?

Comment: I tried plugging in my modem ethernet cable to my computer and my system preferences says its connected but then how do I use the internet with the ethernet

Comment: You go to system preferences/network and then choose ethernet if it's not automatically running. You may have to click "advanced" then TCP/IP and "renew DHCP Lease" if the computer isn't recognizing the modem. Run your browser and see if you're online when you're sure you're connected  directly to the modem.

Comment: @Richard Plugged ethernet in and performed those settings and now the macbook pro with ethernet and the new modem works fine

Comment: When you say works fine, I assume you mean you're online. Next you need to completely reset the AirPort base station plug it into the modem and set it up from scratch.

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: @Richard I have to take the modem thing back, I realized I was running wifi simultaneously so it seemed like the ethernet was working. But now in system preferences the Ethernet thing Is green and working, renewed the DHCP lease, but when I turn WIFI off the internet doesn't work...

Comment: @Richard any suggestions?

Comment: So... uh, let me make sure I've got this straight. You've plugged your computer into the modem. You only get internet when the WiFi is on. If that's correct, then you're empirically doing something wrong - where would the WiFi come from if your computer is plugged into the modem directly?

Comment: To wit, either you're plugging your computer into the wrong place or you've been connecting to a neighbor's WiFi all along.

Comment: @Kerin its because I have another router that I kept it connected to

Comment: Does your modem - from your ISP - have more than one port? Most do not.

Comment: @Kerin no it does not

Comment: @Kerin ok wait I thought it has 2.... it has 4! I thought 2 was normal...... but this has 4 ports

Comment: If your modem has four ports, it's a router-modem combo. This is probably why the AirPort Extreme is having problems. GO into your router's settings and disabling the DHCP server, and then try hooking up the AirPort again.

Comment: @Kerin This is one of the problems, I do not know how to reconfigure the modem settings because I don't know how to get access to it.... when I was away the cable guy came in and installed it but I can't figure out access into it

Comment: @Kerin Ill try to call the cable guys

Comment: generally you'd open your browser and navigate to 192.168.0.1. the default admin credentials for your router model should be located via Google.

Comment: @Kerin via google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amber light could mean many things.

Steps I would take:

Install new firmware http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1481?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Second:

Factory default reset

Does your modem have a router built into it?  If so, you need to put that either into bridge mode or router behind router mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was troubleshooting the Router, I did the reset, created a new network, reset again then I decided to chain the trouble-router with my working Airport extreme.
It obviously gave me the SAME IP RANGE issue.

I opened the options of the Trouble-router and went to NETWORK > NETWORK OPTIONS > and changed the IPv4 CHCP RANGE from 10.0  to  172.16
saved options, connected to the internet modem directly and VOILA.